# is the followng function $f$ surjective?

Tags: geometry, functions, transformational-geometry

$f$ is a function mapping $x$ axis to plane $V$ defined by if $P(x,0)$ then $f(P) = (x,x^2)$ ?

I am not so sure for my following answer :

to show that $f$ is surjective, for every $A(x,x^2)$ there exist $B(x',y')$ element $x$ axis such that $f(B) = A)$.

it is obtained that $x' = x$ and $y'$ equals the square root of $x$.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question

Comment: A function is a mapping from points in a set $A$ to points in a set $B$. In order to show surjectivity, you need to give a mathematical definition of these sets. In your case, A is "the $x$ axis" and $B$ is "the plane $V$". But you need to say more exactly what you mean. Do you mean $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^2$?